# Multiple If in single filter

Tags: logstash

```
 if [CREATION_DATE] == "" 
 {
   mutate {
            convert => [ "CREATION_DATE", "string" ]
          }
 }
 else
 {
   date {
   locale => "en"
   match => [ "CREATION_DATE", "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSS a"]
   target => "CREATION_DATE"
        }
 }  

  if [SUBMITTED_DATE] == "" 
 {
   mutate {
            convert => [ "SUBMITTED_DATE", "string" ]
          }
 }
 else
 {
   date {
   locale => "en"
   match => [ "SUBMITTED_DATE", "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSS a"]
   target => "SUBMITTED_DATE"
        }
 }  

 if [LAST_MODIFIED_DATE] == ""
 {
 mutate {
         convert => [ "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE", "string" ]
      }
 }
 else
 {
   date {
   locale => "en"
   match => [ "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE", "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSS a"]
   target => "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE"
       }
 }'
```

am getting output if i have all three (CREATION_DATE,SUBMITTED_DATE,LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) in date format.If any is    STRING am not getting that log file in my input.
  for ex:
my input is

```
12-JUL-13 11.33.56.259 AM,12-JUL-13 03.59.36.136 PM,12-JUL-13 04.00.05.584 PM
14-JUL-13 11.33.56.259 AM,11-JUL-13 04.00.05.584 PM
```

my output will come successfully for

```
12-JUL-13 11.33.56.259 AM,12-JUL-13 03.59.36.136 PM,12-JUL-13 04.00.05.584 PM
```

but NOT FOR  2nd line

In Simple,Logstash is indexing only when three if clauses have dates.
Help me out.THanks in advance!!

Comment: Why do you convert empty fields into strings? Also check your logstash logs.

Comment: If CREATION_DATE is empty (what you're checking for), then it's already a string and there's no need to convert it.  What would you like these fields to be when they're not present in the input?

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your if statements is pointed out by the comments by @[Fairy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2471940/fairy) and @[alain-collins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/677561/alain-collins).

```
if [CREATION_DATE] == ""
```

Does not check if that field exists, it checks if it is an empty string.

Instead you could use a regex check to see if there is any content in the field using:

```
if [CREATION_DATE] =~ /.*/
```

and perform your date filter when this returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved when i change input format.
(New Format) 11-JUL-13 06.36.33.425000000 PM,13-JUL-13 06.36.33.425000000 PM,,
instead of 
(Old format)11-JUL-13 06.36.33.425000000 PM,13-JUL-13 06.36.33.425000000 PM,"",
But My ques is still open.
I posted this because this solution might be useful to some.
Thanks!!!